# trying to give user Log on as Batch Job permissions in WIX option not appearing

Tags: build, wix, windows-installer, installation

I am trying to set logon as batch Job in WIX for a user.

However, I do not get this option. Please see the image below

I am using wix 3.9 and I have referenced wix util extension. Can somebody please advise?

[clickhereForImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92MSs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You need wix 3.10